# получение json laravel

Tags: json, laravel, post, input

У меня laravel 8.9.
Хочу получить json post.
Если я правильно понял документацию, то для получения всего запроса его нужно передавать с массивом внутри, и получать значения через `$name = $request->input('user.name');`.
Или можно использовать `$data = $request->all();` для получения массива?

Соответственно в контроллере я могу прописать:

```
public function response (Request $request) {
$data = $request->all();
$name = $request->input('user.name');
}
```

И уже обрабатывать данные?

Comment: Да, laravel сам разберет $_GET и $_POST параметры, задекодит json при необходимости

Comment: Ну получать вы можете как угодно. Уточните вопрос, что за json в посте хотите? Форма шлёт json? Вы хотите сформировать json и отправить ответом? Или что?

Если Форма шлёт json строку, то она записана в каком-то одном элементе. Laravel за Вас обрабатывать ничего не будет. `$user = json_decode($request->user, true);`, и дальше уже делайте с этим массивом что-то (но опять же учитывайте, что валидация проходить не будет на каждое поле в отдельности)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar в данном случае планируется, что json будет поступать через апи. Я правильно понимаю, что json должен приходить в таком виде?
``` 
{ 
"user": 
[ name -> John, Age -> 20]
}```